# How would I sort items from an array that have been chosen through checkboxes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to sort the items that have been previously selected with checkboxes. If I select ratings for movies by clicking the checkboxes, it returns the movies that apply.

The end of the URL looks like this:

```
?ratings[PG-13]=1&ratings[G]=1
```

If I click on the link that orders the movies, it takes the whole list of movies and not the ones that I just targeted. So, how can I "append" `"sort=title"` to the ratings in the URL?

I have a feeling it's something I can do in the view. My link_to is this:

```
%th#title_header{:class=>("hilite" if @sort == "title")}= link_to "Movie Title", :sort =>   "title"
```

and my `check_box_tag` is this:

```
= check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]",rating,@all.include?(rating)
```

In my controller, I have this:

```
def index

@movies = Movie.order(params[:sort])
@movies = @movies.where(:rating => params[:ratings].keys) if params[:ratings].present?
@sort = params[:sort]
@all = (params[:ratings].present? ? params[:ratings] : [])

end
```

(I know, my "where" query is vulnerable to SQL injection, it's temporary, I'm just trying to conceptualize the whole thing.)

Comment: have you tried to debug "index" step by step? you should see what's going on. BTW, there is no possible SQL injection in that `where`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass an extra hash at the end of link_to ,it chains the queries in the url:

```
link_to "Movie Title", movies_path(:sort => "title", :ratings => params[:ratings])
```

Brilliant!