# How to link my check box to movie titles in haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails! And I have been working at linking my movie check box to movie titles! I have tried everything!! Currently my movies and check box list display correctly without errors, But when I select check box Ie G, or PG, page refreshes but no sorting occurs!! I am wondering whether I need a special link to chain the check box to movie listing in my index! can some one guide me on how to do this? all efforts due will be most gratified
My Index.html.haml has the following code;

```
%h1 All Movies`enter code here`
    = form_tag XXXXX_path, :method => :get do 
    - Movie.all_ratings.each do |rating|
    = rating
    = check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]", 1, @filtered_ratings.include?(rating) ? true : false
    = submit_tag 'Refresh'
    %table#movies
    %thead
    %tr
    %th{:class=>@title_header, :id=> "title_header"}= link_to "Movie Title",   movies_path(:sort_by => 'title')
    %th Rating
```

Whereas my controller has

```
    def index
    @filtered_ratings = params[:ratings] || [] # if no params[:ratings] then assign empty array
    @movies = Movie.order(params[:sort])
    @movies = @movies.where(rating: params[:ratings]) if params[:ratings].present?
    end        

    @movies = Movie.all(:order => "title ASC, release_date ASC")
    if params[:sort_by] == 'title'
    end 
    end
```

My movie.rb

```
    def Movie.all_ratings
    Array['G','PG','PG-13','R','NC-17']

    end


    end
```

Now I tried passing an extra hash at the end of Link_to... in my index.html.haml;
link_to "Movie Title", movies_path(:sort => "title", :ratings => params[:ratings])
which gave no errors but upon refreshing didnt sort as expected???

Comment: Can you re-format your code with correct indentation please?

Comment: You are using `haml`,i guess there should be `=` before the `link_to` like `= link_to`.Is it a typo in your code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How would I sort items from an array that have been chosen through checkboxes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984890/how-would-i-sort-items-from-an-array-that-have-been-chosen-through-checkboxes)

Comment: @ pavan, thanks for your prompt response, I am using haml and my code line is = link_to "Movie Title", movies_path(:sort_by => 'title') I dont see that typho you mentioned?

Comment: @pavan,its the same issue as the link you posted! I tried implementing the code per that qn! but it didnt work?

Comment: At the last line of your question,you are missing `=` before `link_to`

Comment: Ok thanks I will try to modify.. Will respond in about 10hrs for I get ready for work

Comment: @Pavan, pardon my delayed response! I applied the above modification (=)before link_to, still my check box wont link to the movie list, I wonder what I am missing here?